# Dynamics CRM : How to restrict Lead records being seen by other teams?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

Ours is small company who wants to manage its sales activity on MS Dynamic CRM 2013 online.

There will be two divisions (Sales & Marketing), and they will not see each other’s records except the leads, as they have to work on them together. So, only Leads records will be shared from Marketing division to Sales division.

Under Sales Team, there will be at-least 2 or more sales teams (may be based on locations or products)  working for different accounts. And they also should not see each other’s records except in cases where specific records needs to be shared with another team.

Now, I am trying to understand what is the best solution,

Option 1: Should I create only 1 BU (with Company Name) and with teams for Sales and Marketing division and further teams as required.

[image]
OR

Option 2: Should I create Two BUs (1 for Sales and 1 for Marketing activities under Company Name BU)?

[image]

1. Which option should be advisable in case of my requirements or may be any other suggestions?
2. Sharing leads between Sales and Marketing Divisions and leads can be created by both the divisions.
   Once lead is created, auto notify the concern sales person.
3. Sales and Marketing Managers can manage only their teams, e.g. Sales Manager can’t read/create/Update/delete Marketing activity related teams. (If I design with only 1 BU I think I will not be able to manage this)
4. Occasionally sharing between Sales and Marketing teams as well as sharing between Sales teams.
5. Also, Since I am new to CRM, Can you let me know how we can restrict team users from read/create/Update/delete another team’s records?
6. Also, when we assign any Security Role to the Team, then all the Users belong to that Team will automatically have that Access. How do I restrict this? For Example, Users in the Team are having Security Role as "Sales Person" with Lead Records -Read Permission. And, if I assign "Sales Manager" Security Role to the Team with Lead Records - Full Access. So Now, all team members will have full access to Lead Records. How do I stop this ? Without Assigning any role to Team, I am not able to Assign any records to Team.

Thank you,

Mittal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initial thoughts...

*There will be two divisions (Sales & Marketing), and they will not see each other’s records except the leads, as they have to work on them together.*

business units are the way to go. a BU for sales and a BU for marketing. Sharing leads would be an option but you may want to consider another BU just for leads. It kinda depends on if all leads will be shared or if leads need to be sectioned somehow. Also google for "dynamics 2013 access teams" as that feature may be of use. Also consider the use of teams in general as a team can own a record just as a user can and that can be useful.

*Under Sales Team, there will be at-least 2 or more sales teams (may be based on locations or products) working for different accounts. And they also should not see each other’s records except in cases where specific records needs to be shared with another team.*

Clearly, use teams for this. It may make sense for leads to be owned by a team rather than a user. The difficulty lies in sharing as the default will allow sharing with either/or user/teams. You may need to implement a custom sharing option depending on how you set it up.

*Option 1: Should I create only 1 BU (with Company Name) and with teams for Sales and Marketing division and further teams as required.
Option 2: Should I create Two BUs (1 for Sales and 1 for Marketing activities under Company Name BU)?*

Offhand option 2 sounds better to me in general.

*Once lead is created, auto notify the concern sales person.*

Best way to do notifications is with a workflow, on create of a lead. To notify teams we devised a custom entity called TeamNotifier that has the fields we need for input and takes care of sending email to all users in the team.

*Sales and Marketing Managers can manage only their teams, e.g. Sales Manager can’t read/create/Update/delete Marketing activity related teams. (If I design with only 1 BU I think I will not be able to manage this)*

Not sure I follow this one

*Occasionally sharing between Sales and Marketing teams as well as sharing between Sales teams.*

if leads are owned by teams and you educate your users to share correctly or implement custom sharing, this is easy.

*Also, Since I am new to CRM, Can you let me know how we can restrict team users from read/create/Update/delete another team’s records?*

Welcome to the madness. Record restrictions are user only/BU/BU + children Us/Entire Org. BUs are the general mechanism to apply record restrictions and if records need to be accessible across BUs, sharing is the mechanism for that.

*Also, when we assign any Security Role to the Team, then all the Users belong to that Team will automatically have that Access. How do I restrict this?*

You can't

*For Example, Users in the Team are having Security Role as "Sales Person" with Lead Records -Read Permission. And, if I assign "Sales Manager" Security Role to the Team with Lead Records - Full Access. So Now, all team members will have full access to Lead Records. How do I stop this ?*

You can't

*Without Assigning any role to Team, I am not able to Assign any records to Team.*

Correct. Team security has it nuances but effectively a team is like a user. Whatever roles it has, each member of the team has. Think of teams as people who should have the same security. If they should have different security privs, either the team they are in in reality has no security roles and roles are assigned at the user level or the team has the lowest common security and certain team users get the additional security either directly or because they are in the power user team as well as the common team.

These are all just ideas to mull over. From my experience the only way you'll find the setup that works for you is to try something, fail a few times, drink beer and try the next one. Eventually you'll get it right.

### MORE THOUGHTS AFTER FURTHER QUESTIONS

I have not yet used access teams myself but as I understand them, they are a new feature to get around the old performance problems associated with sharing large amounts of records. [Here](http://garethtuckercrm.com/2013/11/24/crm-2013-new-features-access-teams/)'s a good blog for understanding features. Gareth's pretty good about answering questions so may want to try him.

I doubt if you will be able to achieve what you want with workflows. There just isn't enough OOTB functionality there. Your scenario is complex enough that I reckon you'll need to either simplify it somehow or resort to plugins. With plugins you can do pretty much anything but they are harder to maintain etc. Another code-level option is to create your own workflow activities (i think they are called) to augment the OOTB. Same code but as wf add-ons are re-usable thru the UI.

Looks like an access team can't own a record alright. Remember they exist, as the name implies to access records that could not otherwise be accessed i.e. they are owned by a user1 OR team1 and user2 can't normally access the records unless user2 is in access team1 which has been setup to be able to access records of entity X with certain privs. Again, the older mechanism for this type of thing was sharing (which still exists too). Sharing may work better for your scenario but it has performance issues past a certain amount of sharing. There is a very comprehensive doc available on MS download that goes into as much detail as you could want on the security considerations of crm....ah found [the link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39095)

Read that and if you are still breathing and have more questions, fire away. But I have to say that if you understand that whitepaper, you are ahead of most people!

That's about all I can tell you I'm afraid.

Comment: Hello Keerz, Thank you very much for your wonderful and much descriptive explanation on this.

Comment: Adding more questions for you below. Please help. :)